# what type of variable type has Node in java?

Tags: java, nodes

I'm learning java,and i've seen NODE in some java codes. like in binary tree and etc..
For me everything can contain only `{text(string), numbers, charaters}`, so when I've seen `Node node;` i ve been confused,which type it stores?its string or what else?
so please help me, i am understanding that its object,and object can be null or not null, but i think object also has string or mb int  types (under hood). i'm just newbie, and cant understand it. Thank you)

Comment: shows a [mcve] please.  Nobody here has a clue without some context.  There is no standard definition of a Node.

Comment: Did you heard about "classes" ? There is not only primivites in java, there is also objects : List, Map,, ... and a thousand other

Comment: `Node` isn't a standard thing. Most likely `Node` is a class that is defined in the code you are talking about. So to answer your question, you will have to look at that code to understand what `Node` is. You will need to read more about classes in general and how the store data in fields to understand what is "under the hood".

Answer (score 1):

> For me everything can contain only {text(string), numbers, charaters},
> so when I've seen Node node; i ve been confused,which type it stores?

It seems you have not yet arrived in object oriented programming.

Whatever object you create, it can store text, number characters and code (method pointers). And it can store references to other objects, which again have text, number, characters and code of their own.

The good news is that Java is strongly typed. So for each variable you can lookup the type in your code and rest assured at runtime it will be that type either. Over time you will learn which types are part of the Java runtime, which of them come from libraries or which of them are from your code.

So spend some time being puzzled but do not give up. It's worth it. :-)